# Validation of Email

Tags: php, laravel, validation, email

I have been testing the laravel validations and I have encountered a problem with the email.

When registering with an invalid email, such as 'example@ho.com', 'a@a.com', 'x@hot.com', etc. Log me in and it does not give me any error .. how can I arrange to just ask for a valid email?

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|Regex:/^[\D]+$/i|max:100',
        'last_name' => 'required|Regex:/^[\D]+$/i|max:100',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
   }
```

I've been following the tutorial

> http://www.lubus.in/blog/adding-email-verification-in-laravel-5-3-app-149

But I was getting an error with the router and then I decided to undo all the changes. Any idea?

```
FatalThrowableError in web.php line 14: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'
```

line14

```
Route::get(‘register/verify/{token}’, ‘Auth\RegisterController@verify’);
```

Comment: What is these quotes `‘`? Do you have proper ones `'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 14 to:

```
Route::get('register/verify/{token}', 'Auth\RegisterController@verify');
```

Comment: i recived these error Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
"  any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As for the email validation, you cannot check if the email given actually exists with a script. Laravel's email validator only checks if the email value satisfies a regular expression.

To make sure an email exists, you'll have to send an actual email to this adress, containing a link with a unique token, leading to a verification page. If the verification page is loaded with a valid token, you can flag this address as validated.